# wordpress login - php if statements with fbml conditions?

Tags: php, wordpress, fbml, if-statement

I'm trying to integrate Facebook Connect with my Wordpress installation.
I DO NOT want to use a plugin for this as all the ones I've tried do not give me the scope I need.

I've set everything up giving the user the option to log in (with previously created wordpress details), register (with wordpress) or login with Facebook using

```
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="160" max-rows="2"></fb:login-button>
```

This all works well enough. BUT....

I want to achieve something like the following:

```
    <?php global $user_identity, $user_ID; if (is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
        // Wordpress user details here

    <?php } elseif ***connected with Facebook*** { ?>
        // Facebook user details here

    <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-login.php">Log in (existing users)</a>
        <fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="160" max-rows="2"></fb:login-button>

    <?php } ?>
```

I'm not sure how to integrate the `***connected with Facebook***` part into the php `elseif` statement.

Has anyone done this before or could point me to some understandable documentation on this. The FBML documentation assumes you know a lot already... I don't. :(

Comment: This would be really beneficial to a lot of applications across the web, no-one got any ideas...?

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer quick at www.facebook.com/thefanpagefactory - just post it on the wall or something!

Enjoy.